Как фиксировать IP клиента при запросе в FastAPI?
Структура такая: Клиент стучиться на сервис, который запущен через docker-compose.
В docker-compose запрос принимает сервис NGINX он предает на FastAPI:
app:
  expose:
    - 443
  networks:
    -  net-backend
  ...

nginx:
  ports:
    - 80:80
  volumes:
    - ./nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
  networks:
    -  net-backend
  ...


networks:
  net-backend:
    driver: bridge

./nginx/nginx.conf:
upstream app-server {
    server app:443;
}

server {
     listen 80;
     client_max_body_size 0;

     location / {
        proxy_pass http://app-server;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        real_ip_header X-Forwarded-For;  # Этого нет - просто как пример пробовал передастся ли
    }

}

внутри FastAPI:
from fastapi import Request
class Client():
  def __init__(self, request: Request)
    host_ip = request.client.host
    ...

Соответственно при получение запроса - FastAPI скорее всего получает IP сети docker-compose. Можно ли получить реальный IP клиента?

В nginx вы прописали взять ip из заголовка X-Forwarded-For - а кто вам передаёт этот заголовок и почему вы решили что ему можно доверять?

@andreymal real_ip_header  - это из интернета посмотрел в качестве посмотреть будет ли работать, но оно не работает. Поэтому в реале этого нет

А вот не надо бездумно куски из интернета вставлять, так уязвимости и плодятся ¯\(ツ)/¯ А надо проанализировать весь путь запроса и понять, откуда IP в принципе должен взяться. Если nginx торчит голым портом напрямую в интернет (и перед ним нету какого-нибудь traefik или второго nginx), то значит этот nginx уже получил настоящий IP-адрес от подключившегося к нему клиента, и можно передать его в веб-приложение через какой-нибудь HTTP-заголовок типа proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr; (собственно, в стандартном proxy_params это уже прописано)
